# Regex match all strings except

Tags: regex

I have to create a regex that finds next strings:

> **stackoverflow** //not found
>   **stackexchange** //found 'stackexchange'
>   **stacksomething** //found 'stacksomething '
>   **stacksomething another words** //find 'stacksomething '

Explanation: find a string that:

1. starts with 'stack'
2. ends with any word except 'overflow'
3. find only this word.

I created regex which corresponds to the first point, but can't implement the second and the third. I tried solutions like `^((?!overflow).)*$` and `^(?!.*\boverflow\b)` but they don't work. That's what I have:

```
stack.*
```

Comment: `stackoverflow` is ending with `overflow` then how is this a valid match?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *3. find only this word*?

Comment: For ex., if given string is 'stackexchange blah blah', so find 'stackexchange', not 'stackexchange blah blah'. Anyway, given answer do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
\bstack(?!\w*overflow\b)\w*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD0zG3/1)

**Breakup:**

```
\b                 # word boundary
stack              # match literal text stack
(?!\w*overflow\b)  # negative lookahead to fail the match if word ends with overflow
\w*                # match 0 or more word characters to get full word match
```